# Return one record from my Model based on two parameters sent to my repository asp.net mvc 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2

I pass two parameters to my repository to return one record

I am strugling to wite the code to return one record.

Here is my repository-

```
  public Classifieds_Ads GetUserClassifiedDetailsToModify(int classifiedid, Guid UserGuid)
        {
            return context.Classifieds_Ads.Where(c => c.User.Id == UserGuid && c => c.CatID == classifiedid);        
        }
```

I think you guys can see what I am trying to do but I just write the code. Can I have some help please!

It annoying because I know I will be licking mt self when i see the soloution.

I am also using a stroingly typed views.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public Classifieds_Ads GetUserClassifiedDetailsToModify(int classifiedid, Guid UserGuid)
{
    return context.Classifieds_Ads.Where(c => c.User.Id == UserGuid && c.CatID == classifiedid).First();        
}
```

If your data is returning more than one row you could ask it to return the first row by using the First extension method:

```
Where(c => c.User.Id == UserGuid && c.CatID == classifiedid).First()
```

Comment: In case you don't want an exception if there are no matches, you could also use `.FirstOrDefault()` which will return `null` for value types if no matches are found.

Comment: opps hang on i may have overlooked something.